# How to rotate a View properly in React Native?

Tags: css, react-native, jsx

```
My code 
   <View style={{borderColor:"red",borderWidth:4,flex:1,transform: [{ rotate:'90deg' }]}}>
<Text>Hi</Text>
      </View>
```

result:
[image]

This is not working as I expected. View rotates but width and height is calulated based on phones portait mode and the view is in landscape mode which breaks design.
I tried a work-around as follows

```
import { useWindowDimensions } from 'react-native';
    import React, { useState, useEffect,useCallback, useRef  } from 'react';
    import { Text,View} from "react-native";
    const FullScreenMediaPlayer = (props) => {
      const windowWidth = useWindowDimensions().width;
      const windowHeight = useWindowDimensions().height;
        return (
          <View style={{width:windowHeight,height:windowWidth,borderColor:"red",borderWidth:4,flex:1,transform: [{ rotate:'90deg' }]}}>
    <Text>Hui</Text>
          </View>
        );
    }
    
    export default FullScreenMediaPlayer;
```

Result:
[image]
Views width is still not screens width ?
How can I rotate View and have its height and width same as screen's height and width in landscape mode?

PS: I dont want to use orientation package I just want to achieve this purely based on styles

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: @LeriGogsadze I want to change view to landscape mode without using orientation. I've content inside this view

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useCallback, useRef } from 'react';
import { View, Text, Dimensions } from 'react-native';

const FullScreenMediaPlayer = (props) => {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
      <View
        style={{
          width: Dimensions.get('window').height,
          height: Dimensions.get('window').width,
          borderColor: 'red',
          borderWidth: 4,
          transform: [
            { rotate: '90deg' },
          ],
        }}>
        <Text>Hui</Text>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};

export default FullScreenMediaPlayer;
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know:

1. to set the height and width to 100%, you can use

```js
style={{width: '100%', height: '100%'}}
```

It works for both portrait and landscape orientation

2. to rotate something, you can use (if you're using JSX)

```js
transform: 'rotate(20deg)'
```

So I think the answer is:

```js
<View style={{width: '100%', height: '100%', borderColor:"red", borderWidth:4, flex:1, transform: 'rotate(20deg)'}}>
    <Text>Hui</Text>
</View>
```

Comment: I haven't checked it yet, which one doesn't work? number one or two? @Arjun